# Excel compare by byte array

Tags: c#

I would like to achieve excel sheets comparison by comparing excels sheets transferred into **byte arrays**

Actually my code looks like:

```
public static Document FileToByteArray(string fileName)
{
    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
    System.IO.BinaryReader binaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(fs);

    long byteLength = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName).Length;
    byte[] fileContent = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)byteLength);
    fs.Close();
    fs.Dispose();
    binaryReader.Close();
    Document Document = new Document
    {
        DocContent = fileContent
    };

    return Document;
}

public class Document
{
    public byte[] DocContent { get; set; }
}
```

And finally **main code**:

```
    private static void CompareImportedExportedExcels(string ingredientName, string ingredientsExportFile, AuthorizedLayoutPage authorizedBackofficePage, IngredientsPage ingredientsPage)
    {
        authorizedBackofficePage.LeftMenuComponent.ChooseLeftSectionOption<IngredientsPage>();
        ingredientsPage.FiltersComponent.UseStringFilter(FiltersOptions.IngredientName, ingredientName);
        ingredientsPage.ExportIngredientsElement.Click();

        var downloadResult = DownloadHelper.WaitUntilDownloadedCompare(ingredientsExportFile);
        string ingredientExportExcelFile = DownloadHelper.SeleniumDownloadPath + ingredientsExportFile;

        var exelToByteArray1 = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\..") + @"\TestData\" + "ImportFiles" + @"\IngredientsImport.xlsx");
        var excelArray1 = ExcelsExtensions.FileToByteArray(exelToByteArray1);
        var excelArray2 = ExcelsExtensions.FileToByteArray(ingredientExportExcelFile);
        if (excelArray1.DocContent.Length == excelArray2.DocContent.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excels are equal");
            DownloadHelper.CheckFileDownloaded(ingredientsExportFile);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excels are not equal");
            DownloadHelper.CheckFileDownloaded(ingredientsExportFile);
            Assert.Fail("Seems that imported and exported excels were not the same! Check it!");
        }
    }
```

**What's the current status:**
Above code works correctly speaking about getting `.Lenght` and compare it between two excels. Problem appears with different comparison where firstly the exported excel is placed inside .ZIP file. I need to unpack it and then compare. Although excel sheets are the same `.Lenght` value is different and it fails.

```
 var downloadResult = DownloadHelper.WaitUntilDownloadedCompare(productsExportFile);
                string stockProductZIPFile = DownloadHelper.SeleniumDownloadPath + productsExportFile;
                string stockProductUnzippedFilePath = DownloadHelper.SeleniumDownloadPath + productsExportFile;
                var pathToUnzip = DownloadHelper.SeleniumDownloadPath + productsExportFolderFile;

                ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(stockProductZIPFile);
                zip.ExtractAll(pathToUnzip);

                string stockProductExportedExcel = DownloadHelper.SeleniumDownloadPath + "\\ProductsExport" + @"\Stock Products.xlsx";

                var exelToByteArray1 = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\..") + @"\TestData\" + "ImportFiles" + @"\StockProduct.xlsx");
                var excelArray1 = ExcelsExtensions.FileToByteArray(exelToByteArray1);
                var excelArray2 = ExcelsExtensions.FileToByteArray(stockProductExportedExcel);

                if (excelArray1.DocContent.Length == excelArray2.DocContent.Length)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Excels are equal");
                    DownloadHelper.CheckFileDownloaded(stockProductUnzippedFilePath);
                    DownloadHelper.CheckFileDownloaded(pathToUnzip);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Excels are not equal");
                    DownloadHelper.CheckFileDownloaded(stockProductUnzippedFilePath);
                    DownloadHelper.CheckFileDownloaded(pathToUnzip);
                    Assert.Fail("Seems that imported and exported excels were not the same! Check it!");
                }
```

**Ideas to solve**

First of all I'm not sure if comparing those two by `.Lenght` is good idea. For one case it works but for the other it's not. I'm not sure if it is connected with packing sheet to .zip format and then unpacking it? Actually in second (broken) scenario products size actually differs. Oracle product has 4 KB and exported one has 10 KB (even thought their data inside is the same).

Comment: Just a remark: use `using` blocks when working with objects implementing `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: You aren't comparing files. You are comparing lengths. You are even doing useless things before comparing lengths. You already have the length here: `long byteLength = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName).Length;`. If you want to compare the files content, compare the files content (`excelArray1.DocContent.SequenceEqual(excelArray2.DocContent)`, you'll need a `using System.Linq`).

Comment: And comparing "real" content of Excel file is a very very complex beast. The question has already been asked, with responses of various quality (look for: compare excel c#)

Comment: Last, if you don't need the unzipped excel files, you shouldn't really unzip them to a folder. The ZipFile class has methods to unzip them in memory.

Comment: _Actually in second (broken) scenario products size actually differs. Oracle product has 4 KB and exported one has 10 KB (even thought their data inside is the same)._ Excel files change just by opening and re-saving them. Inside them there is a "field" with the last save date. Sometimes the length doesn't change between saves, sometimes it does. If you create an empty excel an begin saving it without doing anything, you'll see that sometimes the length increases by +1 or -1 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for all the remarks. Actually tried your advice: "(excelArray1.DocContent.SequenceEqual(excelArray2.DocContent)" but I will need to change the main method because "SequenceEqual" method is not possible of being implemented as I'm returning class not a byte array...

Comment: Ok, ok.... missed the sentence about linq, after implementing using it compiles correctly :)